# Backbone "Error: this._configure is not a function"

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

problem with backbone. I'm new to programming with backbone

I have an error of "this._configure is not a function", but earlier versions of "backbone 0.9.2" and "underscore 1.4.1" works well, the problem does not run on ie9 so I want to pass to "backbone 1.0.0 "and" undercore 1.4.4 "and no longer works in any browser.

this is my code:

```
    ////////////// name of space
    var doc;
    var PDF = {
         Models:{}
        ,Collections:{}
        ,Views:{
             Items:{}
            ,Search:{}
            ,Tags:{}
            ,View:{}
        }
        ,Variables:{
             Array:{}
            ,Template:{}
        }
    }
    //////////// json

    PDF.Variables.Array = [
             {'id':0,'name':'Indicadores de Desempeño, Periodo 2004 - 2012','description':'Indicadores de Desempeño, Periodo 2004 - 2012 por SPyDI','url':'../doc/Indicadores-2004-2012.pdf','trumb':'../images/indicadores-2004-2012.png','tags':'Indicadores'}
            ,{'id':1,'name':'Agenda Estadística 2009','description':'Agenda Estadística 2009 por SPyDI','url':'../doc/AE_2009.pdf','trumb':'../images/agenda_2009.png','tags':'Agenda'}
            ,{'id':2,'name':'Agenda Estadística 2010','description':'Agenda Estadística 2010 por SPyDI','url':'../doc/AE_2010.pdf','trumb':'../images/agenda_2010.png','tags':'Agenda'}
            ,{'id':3,'name':'Agenda Estadística 2011','description':'Agenda Estadística 2011 por SPyDI','url':'../doc/AE_2011.pdf','trumb':'../images/agenda_2011.png','tags':'Agenda'}
            ,{'id':4,'name':'Agenda Estadística 2012','description':'Agenda Estadística 2012 por SPyDI','url':'../doc/AE_2012.pdf','trumb':'../images/agenda_2012.png','tags':'Agenda'}
    ]

    PDF.Variables.Template = "<div id='<%=id%>' class='filaGral' onclick='window.open(\"<%=url%>\")'><div class='filaBoxImage'><img src='<%=trumb%>' width='100' height='125' alt='<%=name%>'/></div><div class='filaBoxText'><div class='filaTitle'><%=name%></div><div class='filaText'><%=description%></div></div></div>"

//////////// obj

        PDF.Models = Backbone.Model.extend({
            default:{
                id: -1
                ,name:  'unknow'
                ,description:  'unknow'
                ,url:   '#'
                ,trumb: '/image/PDF.png'
                ,tags:  'Backbone, Underscope'
            }
        });

        PDF.Collections = Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: PDF.Models
            ,initialize:function(){
                console.info('Documentos Inicializados');
            }
            ,filtering:function(value){
                return _(this.filter(function(data){return data.get('tags') == value}));
            }
            ,searching:function(value){
                if(value != "") {
                    var word = new RegExp(value,'gi');
                    return _(this.filter(function(data){ if(data.get('name').search(word) != -1) return data }));

                }else{
                    return this;
                } 

            }

        });
        /////////// view

        PDF.Views.Items = Backbone.View.extend({
             className:'itemDocument'
            ,tagName: 'div'
            ,template:_.template(PDF.Variables.Template)
            ,initialize:function(){
                _.bindAll(this,'render');
            }
            ,render:function(){
                this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
                return this;
            }
        })

        PDF.Views.Search = Backbone.View.extend({
            events:{
                'keyup #searchInput': 'process'
            }
            ,el:$('#questBox')
            ,initialize:function(){
                _.bindAll(this,'process','render');
                this.render();
            }
            ,render:function(){
                $('#searchInput').val('');
            }
            ,process:function(){
                var queryString = this.$el.find('#searchInput').val();
                    this.trigger('request',{QueryString:queryString});
            }
            ,cleaning: function(){
                $('#searchInput').val('');
            }
        })

        PDF.Views.Tags = Backbone.View.extend({
            el:$('#BoxUI')
            ,events:{
                 'click #bu2': 'process1'
                ,'click #bu3': 'process2'
                ,'click #bu4': 'process3'
            }
            ,process1:function(){
                this.send('All');
            }
            ,process2:function(){
                this.send('Indicadores');         
            }
            ,process3:function(){
                this.send('Agenda');      
            }
            ,send:function(value){
                this.trigger('send',{request:value});
            }
        })

        PDF.Views.View = Backbone.View.extend({
            el:$('#content')
            ,initialize:function(){
                _.bindAll(this,'render','show','search');
                this.searchBox = new PDF.Views.Search();
                this.searchBox.on('request',this.search,this);
                this.searchBox.on('clean',this.clean,this);
                this.collection = new PDF.Collections(PDF.Variables.Array);
                this.collection.on('reset',this.show,this);
                this.lateralTags = new PDF.Views.Tags();
                this.lateralTags.on('send', this.sorf, this);
                this.variable = PDF.Variables.Array;
                this.render();
            }
            ,render:function(){
                this.show();
                return this;
            }
            ,show:function(collecion){
                if(collecion == undefined) collecion = this.collection,

                this.$el.find('#listBox').empty();

                collecion.each(function(item){
                    variable = new PDF.Views.Items({model: item});
                        $('#listBox').append(variable.render().el);
                },this)

            }
            ,search:function(data){
                this.show(this.collection.searching(data.QueryString));
            }
            ,sorf:function(value){
                if(value.request == '') value = 'All'
                    if(value.request != 'All'){
                        this.show(this.collection.filtering(value.request));
                        this.searchBox.cleaning();
                    }else{
                        this.show();
                        this.searchBox.cleaning();
                    }
            }
        })
     ////// Run   
        (function($){
            doc = new PDF.Views.View();
        })(jQuery)
```

please i need help, the url of the page is http://observatorio.uaemex.mx/inicio/documentos.php

Comment: TypeError: this._configure is not a function
_updateHash()backbone-min.js (línea 34)
a = function()
anonymous()backbone-min.js (línea 38)
documents.js()documents.js (línea 166)
 
...tend(v.prototype,l,{tagName:"div",$:function(a){return this.$el.find(a)},initial...

Comment: I think you fix it, change this:                            $(document).ready(function() {
        doc = new PDF.Views.View();
}); and remove console.info('Documentos Inicializados'); for problems with ie